# Mapping issue with fill when plotting multiple countries

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, mapping

I am trying to plot a map with Peru and Ecuador, that presents two simple lat and long points (San Jose and Lima in Peru).

I'm having some issue with the fill when incorporating both Peru and Ecuador into my map.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

peru_ecuador <- map_data("world",c("peru", "ecuador"))

# Add study site points (San Jose and Lima)
points <- data.frame(
long = c(-79.81, -77.04),
lat = c(-6.77, -12.04),
names = c("San Jose", "Lima"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


# Plot the map
ggplot() + 
geom_polygon(data = peru_ecuador, aes(x=long, y = lat), fill = "grey40", color 
= "grey90", alpha = 1) +
geom_point(data = points, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "red", size = 2, 
alpha = 0.8) +
geom_text(aes(x = long, y = lat, label = c("San Jose", "Lima")), data = 
points, size = 2, hjust = 1.3) +
geom_area(x = 10) +
coord_fixed(1.3) +
labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", size = 2) +
theme_bw(base_size = 5)
```

I would also really love some advise on how best to resize the plot area window of the map. As in change the x and y axis width and length. When I plot just a map of Peru, some of my map information is cut off by the size of the plot area. Please see below:

```
peru <- map_data("world","peru")
ggplot() + 
geom_polygon(data = peru, aes(x=long, y = lat), fill = "grey40", color = 
  "grey90", alpha = 1) +
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "red", size = 2, 
  alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_text(aes(x = long, y = lat, label = c("San Jose", "Lima")), data = 
  points, size = 2, hjust = 1.3) +
  geom_area(x = 10) +
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", size = 2) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 5)
```